# Why I get "permission denied"?

Tags: bash, macos, macos-catalina

in .sh script when I use this:

```
mdfind -onlyin . -interpret "myLine"
```

I get correct results. But when I use

```
SOME_VAR=`$(mdfind -onlyin . -interpret "$myLine")`;
echo $SOME_VAR;
```

I get `Permission denied` error and empty SOME_VAR. Why and how I can fix it? sudo adding do not helps me.

Same result when using `grep -l -r "$myLine" . -s`

Comment: Remove both backticks \`.

Comment: thanks, it helps me!

Comment: What you are doing is: executing the command in `$(...)` and then you are attempting to execute the **results** of mdfind *as a command* in the backticks

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
SOME_VAR=`mdfind -onlyin . -interpret "$myLine"`
```

Or

```
SOME_VAR=$(mdfind -onlyin . -interpret "$myLine")
```

using both backtick  & `$()` together is your problem.